# Can I create a one way symlink?

Tags: symlink, cd-command, cwd

I want to create a one way symlink i.e. I can use it to go to the destination directory but I cannot go back.

Let's say there is a directory called `D` with two subdirectories `S1` and `S2`. I want to create a link in `S1` that points to `S2` (let's say `ls2 -> ../S2/`). If I do `cd ls2` and then `cd ..` then I want to go to `D` and not `S1`.

Is it possible?

Comment: All symlinks are unidirectional... The ability to go back depends on whether you remember from where you came. So shells do remembers, others don't. Many shells won't remember when you use `cd -P` to change directory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All symbolic links are one-way. As far as the kernel is concerned, after going into `/D/S1` and running `chdir("ls2")`, you're in `/D/S2`, so if you run `chdir("..")`, you end up in `/D`.

If you do this in a shell, after

```
cd /D/S1
cd ls2
cd ..
```

you end up in `/D/S1`. The reason is that the shell does its own tracking of the current directory, and it remembers symbolic links.

You can't disable this shell behavior on a link-by-link basis, but you can disable it when you run the `cd` command. After running `cd ls2`, the shell remembers the current directory as `/D/S1/ls2`:

```
$ pwd
/D/S1
$ cd ls2
$ pwd
/D/S1/ls2
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/D/S1
```

To instruct the shell to forget its symlink-aware current directory tracking, pass the `-P` option to `cd`. The `pwd` command also has a `-P` option.

```
$ pwd
/D/S1
$ cd ls2
$ pwd
/D/S1/ls2
$ pwd -P
/D/S2
$ cd -P ..
$ pwd
/D
```

You can also forget the logical tracking when you change into the symlink:

```
$ pwd
/D/S1
$ cd -P ls2
$ pwd
/D/S2
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/D
```

Comment: A small additional question if it is fine. Is there a way to make the file browser (thunar) forget the symlink track?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I have no idea. You should ask that separately in a question tagged [tag:thunar].